# Chrome not handling chunked responses like Firefox, Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I have a test node server that is sending chunked responses every few two seconds with the following headers:

```
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
```

Every two seconds, I write out to the response:

```
response.write('Hello World');
```

When I do a curl on the endpoint, I get a chunk back every two seconds:

```
Hello World
(wait two seconds)
Hello World
(wait two seconds)
Hello World
```

It works like it's supposed to in curl.

For my Javascript on the client side, I set up a new `XMLHttpRequest` and assign a function to print out its `responseText` for the `onprogress` event.
Here is where the implementation seems to differ across browsers.

In Firefox and Safari, I get similar behavior as when I curl. An onprogress event fires for each "Hello World".

In Chrome, an onprogress event fires only when all of chunks have been received and I do a `response.end()` on the server side. And when I try to print out the `responseText`, only an empty string prints out.

Here is what the client-side code looks like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.onprogress = function() {
  // Firefox, Safari prints out an accumulation of the chunks
  // Chrome prints out an empty string
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Chrome and IE "sniff" the data (the first 256 bytes I believe) in order to detect the mime type. Use this to disable that behavior:

```
response.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
```

Comment: I just got stuck on this, also solved my issue. sniff appears to take place even if you send the Content-Type header which is super strange. Totally tripped me. Not the case in Safari/Firefox.

Comment: I have no words... I have been searching the entire internet for the last 24h to understand why this was happening... I can only say: thank you.